# Keep center, but bring closer elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following snippet (Open as full page):

```css
.navbar {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .20);
    background: #fff;
    border: 0;
    max-height: 65px
}

#navbar_navigation > div.row > div > a{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #244b5a;
}

.navbar_navigation{
     text-align: center;
     font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
     font-size: 22px;
}

.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="row vertical-align">
        <div style="text-align: center; background: red;" class="col-md-2">
            <a href="/">
                Logo
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar_navigation" class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div style="background: gray;" class="col-md-3 navbar_navigation">
                    <a href="#">My menu 1</a>
                </div>
                <div style="background: purple;" class="col-md-3 navbar_navigation">
                    <a href="#">Prices</a>
                </div>
                <div style="background: green;" class="col-md-3 navbar_navigation">
                    <a href="#">Help Me Please</a>
                </div>
                <div style="background: yellow;" class="col-md-3 navbar_navigation">
                    <a href="#">My account</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="background: red; text-align: center" class="col-md-1">
            <a href="#">
                TXT
            </a>
        </div>
        <div style="background: blue;" class="col-md-1">
            <a href="#">
                <div style="float: right; width: 65px; height: 65px; background: #2d4c55;"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I want to bring closer to each other the elements `My menu 1`, `Prices`, `Help Me Please` and`My account` but keep the same margin for all elements.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by bring closer ? make their width smaller ?

Comment: To bring closer text to each other

Comment: So....make their width smaller ? :)) Because i think you still want each text to remain in the middle of its container. And what does `keep the same margin for all elements.` mean exactly ?

Comment: How can I make the width smaller if I'm using the bootstrap grid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to make them smaller. So their texts will be ' closer '.

If you want to keep the `navbar_navigation` width as it is now, then you could add 2 empty cols inside the row with a bs class ( for eg `col-md-1` ). Then you have 10 cols left. Make a `col-md-10` and wrap the 4 `col-md-3` inside that col.

So the result is that the 4 cols are still equal but smaller so the text is 'closer'. The 
`navbar_navigation` has the same width ( this is what i guess you mean when you say you want to keep the margins ).

Check code snippet below in `Full Page`.

As a side note. Do not use float. Stick to bootstrap and flexbox.

```css
.navbar {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .20);
    background: #fff;
    border: 0;
    max-height: 65px
}

#navbar_navigation > div.row > div > a{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #244b5a;
}

.navbar_navigation{
     text-align: center;
     font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
     font-size: 22px;
}

.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="row vertical-align">
        <div style="text-align: center; background: red;" class="col-md-2">
            <a href="/">
                Logo
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar_navigation" class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-1 navbar_navigation">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                <div style="background: gray;" class="col-md-3 navbar_navigation">
                    <a href="#">My menu 1</a>
                </div>
                <div style="background: purple;" class="col-md-3 navbar_navigation">
                    <a href="#">Prices</a>
                </div>
                <div style="background: green;" class="col-md-3 navbar_navigation">
                    <a href="#">Help Me Please</a>
                </div>
                <div style="background: yellow;" class="col-md-3 navbar_navigation">
                    <a href="#">My account</a>
                </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-1 navbar_navigation">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="background: red; text-align: center" class="col-md-1">
            <a href="#">
                TXT
            </a>
        </div>
        <div style="background: blue;" class="col-md-1">
            <a href="#">
                <div style="float: right; width: 65px; height: 65px; background: #2d4c55;"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```